# Convert ArrayList to TreeMap

Tags: java

I have a little problem of understanding, I will put the code here and try to explain my problem.

I have a first class, ReadSymptomFromDataFile :

```java
package com.hemebiotech.analytics;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Simple brute force implementation
 *
 */
public class ReadSymptomDataFromFile implements ISymptomReader {

    private final String filepath;

    /**
     *
     * @param filepath a full or partial path to file with symptom strings in it, one per line
     */
    public ReadSymptomDataFromFile (String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSymptoms () {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (filepath != null) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(filepath));
                String line = reader.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    result.add(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

This class is used to read a txt file which contains a list of symptoms, with several times the same symptoms inside, hence the value of the TreeMap, a symptom associated with the number of times it appears. (Value, Key)
So far so good.

Then I have this code that I made myself but it happens from the class ReadSymptomData :

```java
package com.hemebiotech.analytics.Test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class MainAppTest2 {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {
            File file = new File ("Project02Eclipse\\symptoms.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (file);

            Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new TreeMap<> ();
            while (scan.hasNext ()) {
                String word = scan.next ();
                if (!wordCount.containsKey (word)) {
                    wordCount.put (word, 1);
                } else {
                    wordCount.put (word, wordCount.get (word) + 1);
                }
            }

            // Result in console & Write file output
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter ("resultat2.out");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter (writer);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordCount.entrySet ()) {
                System.out.println ("Valeur: " + entry.getKey () + "| Occurence: " + entry.getValue ());
                out.write (entry.getKey () + " = " + entry.getValue () + " \n");
                out.flush (); // Force write
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ("Fichier introuvable");
        }

    }
}
```

This code does much the same thing, it reads a txt file, saves it in a TreeMap, displays it on the console and saves it in a resultat file.

Now my problem is that I am trying to split my code into several classes while using the already existing class ReadSymptomData, one class to read the text file, another to convert it all to TreeMap, another class to write the results in an output file, and a final one for exception handling.

I started with this FileToTreeMap class, but it's ugly, it's not clean, and I'm sure it can be done better to convert my ReadSymptomDataFromFile object to a TreeMap:

```java
package com.hemebiotech.analytics.Test.read;

import com.hemebiotech.analytics.ReadSymptomDataFromFile;

import java.util.*;

public class FileToTreeMap {

    // Read file
    public Map<String, Integer> readFile () {

        ReadSymptomDataFromFile list = new ReadSymptomDataFromFile ("Project02Eclipse\\symptoms.txt");
        Map<String, Integer> listSort = new TreeMap<> ();
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<> (list.getSymptoms ());

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (String.valueOf (test));
        while (scan.hasNext ()) {
            String word = scan.next ();
            if (!listSort.containsKey (word)) {
                listSort.put (word, 1);
            } else {
                listSort.put (word, listSort.get (word) + 1);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : listSort.entrySet ()) {
            System.out.println ("Valeur: " + entry.getKey () + " Occurence: " + entry.getValue ());
        }


        return listSort;
    }

}
```

Here, I am a little lost in cutting my code, and the main problem I have is to convert my ArrayList to a TreeMap.

Sorry for the length of the post, but I would appreciate any help I get, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question, you can always delete it if you prefer

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through list and put the elements in the map. Since this is an arrayList duplicate elements would stay. But beforehand couldn't get why you have to read some data to a list and some to treeMap? You have already been loading your symptoms data to a treeMap. So the code stub is more like

```
for(String el : test) {
 if(!listSort.containsKey(el))
  listSort.put(el,1);
 else
  listSort.put(el, listSort.get(el)+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list into a map, what you can do is use a *for loop*, which goes through the list and adds each item one by one:

```
        ReadSymptomDataFromFile list = new ReadSymptomDataFromFile("Project02Eclipse\\symptoms.txt");
        Map<String, Integer> listSort = new TreeMap<>();
        List<String> test = list.getSymptoms();

        for (String word : test) {
            if (!listSort.containsKey(word)) {
                listSort.put(word, 1);
            } else {
                listSort.put(word, listSort.get(word) + 1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in `Java 8`

```java
final List<String> symptomList;
final Map<String, Integer> countedSymptoms;
symptoms.forEach((symptom) -> 
    countedSymptoms.put(symptom, Collections.frequency(symptomList, symptom)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the merge method of Map:

```
List<String> symptoms = List.of("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b", "c");
Map<String, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();
symptoms.forEach(s -> counts.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum));

counts.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

This prints:

```
a: 2
b: 4
c: 3
```